# mysql + issues with JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join

Ok folks, im sorry to ask about this since ive seen a couple of mysql JOIN examples but i seem to be unable to get it to work.

"sales"

```
----------------------
idcustomer | datecode 
----------------------
 1         | 20120503 
 1         | 20120503 
 1         | 20120503 
 2         | 20120503 
 3         | 20120503
```

I want to know who is the top buyer.... in terms of HOW MANY TIMES a customer buys something from me on a especific day (yes i use some weird format for date i know, please nevermind that)...so i do:

```
SELECT idcustomer, COUNT(idcustomer) FROM sales WHERE datecode = 20120503 GROUP BY idcustomer ORDER BY COUNT(idcustomer) DESC
```

AND I GET:

```
-----------------------------
idcustomer | Count(idcustomer)
-----------------------------
 1         | 3
 2         | 1
 3         | 1
```

Question is... since i also have the table:

"customer"

```
----------------------
| name | id_customer |
----------------------
 Jess  | 1
 Matt  | 2
 Perry | 3
```

And below is what i would like to achieve.... how to do so?

```
---------------------------------------------
customer.name | idcustomer | Count(idcustomer)
---------------------------------------------
 Jess         | 1          | 3
 Matt         | 2          | 1
 Perry        | 3          | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT customer.name, idcustomer, COUNT(idcustomer)
FROM sales
JOIN customer
ON sales.idcustomer = customer.id_customer
WHERE datecode = 20120503
GROUP BY idcustomer
ORDER BY COUNT(idcustomer) DESC
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9edd/3)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Loved the sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it this way -

```
SELECT idcustomer, c.name, COUNT(idcustomer) 
FROM sales s inner join customer c on (s.idcoustomer=c.id_customer)  
WHERE datecode = 20120503 
GROUP BY idcustomer, c.name  
ORDER BY COUNT(idcustomer) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help ::

```
Select cust_ref.idcustomer, cust_ref.COUNT(idcustomer), customer.name
from 
(SELECT idcustomer, COUNT(idcustomer) FROM sales WHERE datecode = 20120503 
 GROUP BY idcustomer) cust_ref
 inner join customer on (sales.idcustomer = customer.id_customer)
ORDER BY COUNT(idcustomer) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t1.name,t2.count_buy,t2.idcustomer 
   FROM customer as t1,
 (SELECT 
    idcustomer,COUNT(idcustomer) as count_buy 
       FROM `sales`  
        WHERE datecode = 20120503
        GROUP BY idcustomer 
         ORDER BY COUNT(idcustomer) DESC) t2
  WHERE 
   t1.idcustomer =t2.idcustomer
```

Comment: This method i have not seen before. I shall investigate further into it. ty